# How to detect what changed a @Published value in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have an `ObservableObject` with a `@Published` value, how can I detect if the value was changed via `TextField` view or it was set directly (When `Button` is tapped for instance)?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("set value") {
                self.model.value = "user set value"
            }
            TextField("value", text: $model.value)
        }
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {

     @Published var value = ""

     var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?

      init() {
          anyCancellable = $value.sink { val in
              // if changed by Button then ...
              // if changed by TextField then ...
          }
      }
}
```

My real case scenario sounds like this: when the user changes the value a request have to be sent to the server with the new value, but the server can also respond with a new value (in that case a new request to server should not be sent), so I have to distinguish between the case when the user changes the value (via TextField) and the case when the server changes the value.

Comment: In both cases there is no *changer* (or, if you like, *sender* as is in UIKit), the model is changed directly, by assignment, from within some closure, on stack (like `var a = 0; a = 2` - who is sender?).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `@Binding` easily. I don't think you need to use `@Published`
If you still want to use it you can try this code

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("set value") {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                     self.model.value = "user set value"
                }
            }
            TextField("value", text: $model.value)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `onEditingChanged` closure to the [`TextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield) initializer. You should use the closure to trigger the server request.

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("set value") {
                self.model.value = "user set value"
            }
            TextField(
                "value",
                text: $model.value,
                onEditingChanged: { _ in self.model.sendServerRequest() )
        }
    }
}
```